# Snapsvg Element Display Order Issue

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I am using snapsvg.io library and unsure why the following code is not displaying my rectangle with text over my svg line element.

Based on the order I have placed my code, I assumed that my rect/text group would be on top of my line but unfortunately this is not the case and can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

The code sample I have is as follows:

```
line = s.line(trunkLeftPos, 100, trunkLeftPos, 440);
line.attr({
  stroke: error1 ? alert : error2 ? alert : stroke,            
  strokeWidth: 1
});

var text = s.text(trunkLeftPos + 4, trunkLeftTextPos, 'my text');

text.attr({
  fill: error1 ? alert : error2 ? alert : textColorOK,            
  fontSize: '11px',
  'font-weight': '600',
  'font-family': 'Arial Narrow, sans-serif',
  'text-anchor': 'start',
  cursor: error1 ? 'pointer' : error2 ? 'pointer' : 'default',            
});

var rect_bg = s.rect(trunkLeftPos + 2, trunkLeftTextPos - 10, 50, 13, 0, 0).attr({fill: "rgb(236, 240, 241)",stroke: "#1f2c39",strokeWidth: 1});                
var g0 = s.g(rect_bg,text);
```

What I have tried to show you here is the order of play where I expected my g0 element to be placed over my line element but from what I can see, the vertical line appears over the top of my g0 element and not below it.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the values for all your variables, e.g. `trunkLeftPos` and `trunkLeftTextPos`? A JSFiddle would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just created a codepen example and looks like all worked fine with the sample test within my codepen based on the same display order I have presented above.

Looks like I need to look at my values as indicated by @Sphinxxx

See: http://codepen.io/tonyf/pen/KMzvRe?editors=1010

```
<svg id="svg" width="400" height="400"></svg>

const s = Snap("#svg");
const line = s.line(0, 0, 40, 200);
line.attr({
  stroke: 'green',            
  strokeWidth: 2
});

const text = s.text(0 + 14, 100, 'my text');
text.attr({
  fill: 'red',            
  fontSize: '11px',
  'font-weight': '600',
  'font-family': 'Arial Narrow, sans-serif',
  'text-anchor': 'start'       
});

const rect_bg = s.rect(0 + 10, 90, 50, 13, 0, 0).attr({
  fill: "#fff",
  stroke: "#1f2c39",
  strokeWidth: 0.5
});                

const g0 = s.g(rect_bg,text);
```